# How to sort array of objects with forEach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, foreach

I have an array that looks like this:

```
order = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ];
```

This array contains the attribute values I would like to sort my array of objects by. I want to sort the data so that all the objects with name "foo" are first, then "bar", then "baz". My array of objects looks something like this:

```
data = [ 
    {name: "foo", score: 8},
    {name: "baz", score: 4},
    {name: "baz", score: 9}, 
    {name: "foo", score: 6}, 
    {name: "bar", score: 9} 
];
```

I want to outcome of the data order to look like this, the array is ordered by name but also by score desc when the names are the same:

```
sortedData =  [ 
    {name: "foo", score: 8},
    {name: "foo", score: 6},  
    {name: "bar", score: 9},
    {name: "baz", score: 9},
    {name: "baz", score: 4} 
];
```

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
order.forEach(name => {
      sortedData = [...this.data].sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
            return (
              -(obj1.name)  || obj2.score < obj1.score
            );
          });
        });
console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: If you don't want the original array to be mutated and instead a new sorted array to be returned then please check my answer also!

Answer (score 1):

Use the index to sort based on the order, to get index you can use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. To sort based on the number just return the difference.

```
//  extract object properties for comparing
// return difference of indexes to sort based on that
// in case indexes are same return difference of score(to sort element with same name) 
data.sort(({ name: a, score: as }, { name: b ,score: bs}) => order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b) || bs - as)
```

```js
let order = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
let data = [{
    name: "foo",
    score: 8
  },
  {
    name: "baz",
    score: 4
  },
  {
    name: "baz",
    score: 9
  },
  {
    name: "foo",
    score: 6
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    score: 9
  }
];


data.sort(({ name: a, score : as }, { name: b ,score:bs}) => order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b) || bs - as)

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I also sort by score aswell, when  run the code "baz" is not sorted by score too

Comment: @TeamCafe : updated, anyways ascending or descending ?

Comment: By Descending so that the biggest score is at the top

Comment: @TeamCafe : done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `sort` and `indexOf`

```js
let order = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ];

let data = [ 
    {name: "foo", score: 8},
    {name: "baz", score: 4},
    {name: "baz", score: 9}, 
    {name: "foo", score: 6}, 
    {name: "bar", score: 9} 
];

let op = data.sort((a,b)=> (order.indexOf(a.name) - order.indexOf(b.name)) || b.score - a.score )

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however the code snippet result does not seem to have the objects of name "baz" sorted by score descending

Comment: @TeamCafe in snippet it's there in descending order only. cross check once more mtae :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

We can use the array indices in the order array for sorting. 
Also using object destructuring assignment to get the object keys for comparison. 
If the first comparison of `name` key results in equality of the two keys then going for the second criteria of the `score` key.

In my answer I did not ***mutate*** the original array, if that kind of behavior is needed you can check this solution:

```js
const order = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ];
const data = [ 
    {name: "foo", score: 8},
    {name: "baz", score: 4},
    {name: "baz", score: 9}, 
    {name: "foo", score: 6}, 
    {name: "bar", score: 9} 
];
function sortArray(data, order){
  const sortedArr = Array.from(data).sort(({name: name1, score: score1},{name: name2, score: score2}) =>{
     return name1 === name2 ? score2 - score1 : order.indexOf(name1) - order.indexOf(name2);
  });
  return sortedArr;
}
console.log("***Sorted Array***");
console.log(sortArray(data, order));
console.log("***Original Array***");
console.log(data);
```